# Can XSL / XML be used to change iPhone UI / Functionality?

Tags: iphone

If I develop an iPhone application with XML parser (UI will be constructed from XML pushed from the server), can I change the UI / functionality by pushing a new XML file from the backend server?  Would apple allow it?

Answer (score 0):

If they don't find out, they can't not allow it. If you do it correctly I don't see how they will know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask, the answer is probably no they wouldn't allow it.  Whether they'll catch you, of course, is another matter.

The general principle I believe they are trying to enforce is that you can't change the functionally radically after they have approved it.  Thus, no downloading new dynamic libraries, etc.

They haven't precluded you using their built-in engine to execute Javascript so they aren't stopping you from changing what an app does, if the functionality is defined solely on an external website.  But that's not going to change what the app does, merely the information it displays (from there perspective).  I wouldn't mind betting that if you tried to execute *local* javascript, they'd probably reject it, and thus you won't be able to "download" new functionality from a backend server.  In fact, you probably have to walk a pretty fine line in actually using Webkit to execute the Javascript in such a way that your app wasn't dismissed as "just another browser; too confusing to the user"

This is, of course, merely conjecture on my part.